# How to prevent a Hadoop job to fail when directory is empty?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapr

I have a job that fails when there is no files in the input directory. The exception i get is the following:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException:Input Pattern maprfs:/profile/*
```

I know this exception is coming from the FileInputFormat class. What would be the best approach for this problem. Would overwriting the InputFormat Class be the only solution?

Thank you

Comment: what is the requirement to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put an empty file in your input path.
2. At the beginning of your driver list your Input path(S). If there isn’t a file, then exit without submit the job.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I did.